# Is Ingress-Nginx able to send unescape header to backend?

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress, wso2-identity-server

I'm using Nginx as my Ingress Controller in a Kubernetes deployment where WSO2 Identity Server 5.11 is at the backend.

I have a requirement of authenticating clients against the backend using a X509 certificate.
Also, I have to TLS terminate at Nginx.

I managed to put the corresponding certificate from the handshaking to a header in order to pass the request to the backend like WSO2 Identity Server is expecting.

The issue I'm facing is WSO2 Identity server requires the content of the header to be a standard PEM format, which means not escaped/encoded, just standard Base64 and Nginx send the header escaped (see below for a sample).
I tried using a lua block which effectively unescape the original value to the format I would like to send to the backend, but when the header is received at the backend it's always escaped.

Is there any way to send the content of a header unescaped?

Please help, any comments will be greatly appreciated.

Sample of the escaped certificate received by WSO2 Identity Server:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----%0AMIIEDjCCAvagAwIBAgIUCG/WzR4Z p1qGX9 lNVU f0K8P4wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL%0ABQAwgZYxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkNBMQ8wDQYDVQQIDAZRdWViZWMxETAPBgNVBAcMCE1v%0AbnRyZWFsMRAwDgYDVQQKDAdDaGFrcmF5MQswCQYDVQQLDAJJVDEYMBYGA1UEAwwP%0ASmFpcm8gRmVybmFuZGV6MSowKAYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhtqYWlyby5mZXJuYW5kZXpA%0AY2hha3JheS5jb20wHhcNMjExMTMwMjEzNTIyWhcNMjIxMTMwMjEzNTIyWjCBmjEL%0AMAkGA1UEBhMCQ0ExDzANBgNVBAgMBlF1ZWJlYzERMA8GA1UEBwwITW9udHJlYWwx%0AEDAOBgNVBAoMB0NoYWtyYXkxCzAJBgNVBAsMAklUMRwwGgYDVQQDDBNjbGllbnRz%0ALmNoYWtyYXkuY29tMSowKAYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhtqYWlyby5mZXJuYW5kZXpAY2hh%0Aa3JheS5jb20wggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQC nYoRD/83%0AW9OYGMyp2wGhoMPcra2rPgHZf5irCupAIY/49gg1dsz/i7UMj2pK0IzW/dsGTdfl%0AGKuM4avKSqyAjlRvOhxk0A5Z/fmghjOiTWtBdp7jQ4zJcM9ip3 W4nRPi8Asv/A %0AeJyHcCCMppv0XguQKEhwusOyQHCNn7iQ0itT1kPfOAACpi0ZrcN777VlVZRu2LsW%0AdJfYUI1 e7u2OygCdL0B3HGbOZixoOJWEyoi1 0jiIxQmnv2ExDsabjbbdllus8 %0AJDdMUtswo xzGAe0IvGhHiFSOgNTSafLrHpYwCpG3/ikKQ SeULDF9yQ7F09bjpk%0AcyY7GgvaFUZ3AgMBAAGjTjBMMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFA1dKwqVgKPAg/2ciw6MyKGZ%0AsBg8MAkGA1UdEwQCMAAwHgYDVR0RBBcwFYITY2xpZW50cy5jaGFrcmF5LmNvbTAN%0ABgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAutYrzNJs92xXsJh kX7jvK9LZmP5F nsnSOLrM65%0Aa3jv4fkFalFTqx 82ie6ouekaTd9o4JF2jFkmj6B18AteuiM0xesO1ROdp pobZQ%0AfbGT8czViCQjtjiv1OC35unR2AkB9G22jD4OKaAh47T090QHCYGLpLloZrTGISbH%0ArNDGXeZjkTWhymuA1sSRUVIIytHqSzQmNOXC1RHK/ORcy mujOK7zKuLM6jaCgO%0A3FGQ1gh9FF2ooDN8GH9tqo5lzxfKtqd2z4HZ1yQ5QGWTDkHFeOJu6iSzLnO3Nayx%0A6a2 ud8QeN1nZKoMWDy4/BsRilE6Ap/ijQF82g BI/FyUw==%0A-----END CERTIFICATE-----%0A
```

What I really need to send to the backend:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEDjCCAvagAwIBAgIUCG/WzR4Z p1qGX9 lNVU f0K8P4wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
BQAwgZYxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkNBMQ8wDQYDVQQIDAZRdWViZWMxETAPBgNVBAcMCE1v
bnRyZWFsMRAwDgYDVQQKDAdDaGFrcmF5MQswCQYDVQQLDAJJVDEYMBYGA1UEAwwP
SmFpcm8gRmVybmFuZGV6MSowKAYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhtqYWlyby5mZXJuYW5kZXpA
Y2hha3JheS5jb20wHhcNMjExMTMwMjEzNTIyWhcNMjIxMTMwMjEzNTIyWjCBmjEL
MAkGA1UEBhMCQ0ExDzANBgNVBAgMBlF1ZWJlYzERMA8GA1UEBwwITW9udHJlYWwx
EDAOBgNVBAoMB0NoYWtyYXkxCzAJBgNVBAsMAklUMRwwGgYDVQQDDBNjbGllbnRz
LmNoYWtyYXkuY29tMSowKAYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhtqYWlyby5mZXJuYW5kZXpAY2hh
a3JheS5jb20wggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQC nYoRD/83
W9OYGMyp2wGhoMPcra2rPgHZf5irCupAIY/49gg1dsz/i7UMj2pK0IzW/dsGTdfl
GKuM4avKSqyAjlRvOhxk0A5Z/fmghjOiTWtBdp7jQ4zJcM9ip3 W4nRPi8Asv/A
eJyHcCCMppv0XguQKEhwusOyQHCNn7iQ0itT1kPfOAACpi0ZrcN777VlVZRu2LsW
dJfYUI1 e7u2OygCdL0B3HGbOZixoOJWEyoi1 0jiIxQmnv2ExDsabjbbdllus8
JDdMUtswo xzGAe0IvGhHiFSOgNTSafLrHpYwCpG3/ikKQ SeULDF9yQ7F09bjpk
cyY7GgvaFUZ3AgMBAAGjTjBMMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFA1dKwqVgKPAg/2ciw6MyKGZ
sBg8MAkGA1UdEwQCMAAwHgYDVR0RBBcwFYITY2xpZW50cy5jaGFrcmF5LmNvbTAN
BgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAutYrzNJs92xXsJh kX7jvK9LZmP5F nsnSOLrM65
a3jv4fkFalFTqx 82ie6ouekaTd9o4JF2jFkmj6B18AteuiM0xesO1ROdp pobZQ
fbGT8czViCQjtjiv1OC35unR2AkB9G22jD4OKaAh47T090QHCYGLpLloZrTGISbH
rNDGXeZjkTWhymuA1sSRUVIIytHqSzQmNOXC1RHK/ORcy mujOK7zKuLM6jaCgO
3FGQ1gh9FF2ooDN8GH9tqo5lzxfKtqd2z4HZ1yQ5QGWTDkHFeOJu6iSzLnO3Nayx
6a2 ud8QeN1nZKoMWDy4/BsRilE6Ap/ijQF82g BI/FyUw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have used $ssl_client_escaped_cert in the cert header, it returns the client certificate in the PEM format which is urlencoded.

> proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT ssl_client_escaped_cert;

Intead, try using the $ssl_client_cert as follows.

> **proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_cert;**

OR

> **proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_raw_cert;**

It will return the client certificate in the PEM format for an established SSL connection without any encoding.
Refer [1] for more information on nginx embedded variables.

Note: Replace X-SSL-CERT with your corresponding HTTP request header name.

If this solution didn't resolve the issue, please attach your nginx.conf configurations for further investigations.

[1] http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html